# Крашится приложение на PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, qlabel, qlineedit, qcheckbox

Делаю калькулятор расхода калорий на *Python*, с использованием *PyQt5*.

Именно в данной части кода приложение крашится:

```
...

self.PolMuzh.stateChanged.connect(self.calc_logic1)
self.PolZhen.stateChanged.connect(self.calc_logic2)


    # логика калькулятора расхода калорий для мужчин
    def calc_logic1(self, toggle):
        if toggle == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            self.PolZhen.setEnabled(False)

            if self.ComboFizAkt.currentText() == 'Сидячий' and self.ComboCel.currentText() == 'Ничего не хочу' and self.ComboTrenirovki.currentText() == '0':
                string_vozrast = self.LineVozrast.text()
                string_vozrast1 = int("0" + "".join(list(map(str, re.findall(r'\d+', string_vozrast)))))
                if 10 <= string_vozrast1 < 112:
                    string_ves = self.LineVes.text()
                    string_ves1 = int("0" + "".join(list(map(str, re.findall(r'\d+', string_ves)))))
                    if 635 > string_ves1 >= 30:
                        string_rost = self.LineRost.text()
                        string_rost1 = int("0" + "".join(list(map(str, re.findall(r'\d+', string_rost)))))
                        if 272 > string_rost1 >= 55:
                            muzh_rashod = 5 + (10 * string_ves1) + (6.25 * string_rost1) - (5 * string_vozrast1)
                            self.LineVivodCalc.setText(muzh_rashod)
        else:
            self.PolZhen.setEnabled(True)
            self.LineVivodCalc.setText('Вы ввели неверные данные!')

    # логика калькулятора расхода калорий для женщин
    def calc_logic2(self, toggle):

        if toggle == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            self.PolMuzh.setEnabled(False)

            if self.ComboFizAkt.currentText() == 'Сидячий':
                if self.ComboCel.currentText() == 'Ничего не хочу':
                    if self.ComboTrenirovki.currentText() == '0':
                        string_vozrast = self.LineVozrast.text()
                        string_vozrast1 = int("0" + "".join(list(map(str, re.findall(r'\d+', string_vozrast)))))
                        if 10 <= string_vozrast1 < 112:
                            string_ves = self.LineVes.text()
                            string_ves1 = int("0" + "".join(list(map(str, re.findall(r'\d+', string_ves)))))
                            if 635 > string_ves1 >= 30:
                                string_rost = self.LineRost.text()
                                string_rost1 = int("0" + "".join(list(map(str, re.findall(r'\d+', string_rost)))))
                                if 272 > string_rost1 >= 55:
                                    zhen_rashod = (10 * string_ves1) + (6.25 * string_rost1) - (5 * string_vozrast1) - 161
                                    self.LineVivodCalc.setText(zhen_rashod)
            else:
                self.PolMuzh.setEnabled(True)
                self.LineViodCalc.setText('Вы ввели неверные данные!')


...
```

`PolMuzh`, `PolZhen` - два `QCheckBox`, которые отвечают за пол пользователя.

`ComboFizAkt`, `ComboCel`, `ComboTrenirovki` - три `QComboBox`, которые отвечают за вид физической активности пользователя (сидячий, слабый физ. труд и т.д.), цель пользователя ( хочу похудеть, хочу улучшить фигуру и т.д. ) и количество тренировок в неделю соответственно.

`LineVozrast`, `LineVes`, `LineRost` - три `QLineEdit`, в которые пользователь вводит свои возраст, вес и рост соответственно.

В данном отрывке кода я хотел вычислить суточный расход калорий для мужчин и для женщин.

Числа из `QLineEdit` переведены в `int()`, но почему-то именно в этой части кода происходит краш.

---

**Дополнительно**:

```
self.PolMuzh.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Мужской"))
self.PolZhen.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Женский"))
self.UkazatVes.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Вес"))
self.UkazatRost.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Рост"))
self.ComboFizAkt.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Сидячий"))
self.ComboFizAkt.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "Слабый физ. труд"))
self.ComboFizAkt.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "Преобладает физ. труд"))
self.ComboFizAkt.setItemText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "Тяжёлый физ. труд"))
self.ComboFizAkt.setItemText(4, _translate("MainWindow", "Очень тяжёлый физ. труд"))
self.ComboCel.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Ничего не хочу"))
self.ComboCel.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "Хочу похудеть"))
self.ComboCel.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "Хочу улучшить фигуру"))
self.ComboCel.setItemText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "Хочу набрать мыш. массу"))
self.ComboTrenirovki.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "0"))
self.ComboTrenirovki.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "1"))
self.ComboTrenirovki.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "2"))
self.ComboTrenirovki.setItemText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "3"))
self.ComboTrenirovki.setItemText(4, _translate("MainWindow", "4"))
self.ComboTrenirovki.setItemText(5, _translate("MainWindow", "5"))
self.ComboTrenirovki.setItemText(6, _translate("MainWindow", "6"))
self.ComboTrenirovki.setItemText(7, _translate("MainWindow", "7+"))

self.ViborPola = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
self.ViborPola.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(790, 370, 81, 51))
self.ViborPola.setObjectName("ViborPola")
self.PolMuzh = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
self.PolMuzh.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(880, 370, 70, 17))
self.PolMuzh.setObjectName("PolMuzh")
self.PolZhen = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
self.PolZhen.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(880, 400, 70, 17))
self.PolZhen.setObjectName("PolZhen")
self.LineVozrast = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
self.LineVozrast.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(880, 200, 71, 51))
self.LineVozrast.setObjectName("LineVozrast")
self.LineVes = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
self.LineVes.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(880, 250, 71, 51))
self.LineVes.setObjectName("LineVes")
self.LineRost = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
self.LineRost.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(880, 300, 71, 51))
self.LineRost.setObjectName("LineRost")
self.ComboFizAkt = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
self.ComboFizAkt.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(780, 70, 171, 22))
self.ComboFizAkt.setObjectName("ComboFizAkt")
self.ComboFizAkt.addItem("")
self.ComboFizAkt.addItem("")
self.ComboFizAkt.addItem("")
self.ComboFizAkt.addItem("")
self.ComboFizAkt.addItem("")
self.ComboCel = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
self.ComboCel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(780, 120, 171, 22))
self.ComboCel.setObjectName("ComboCel")
self.ComboCel.addItem("")
self.ComboCel.addItem("")
self.ComboCel.addItem("")
self.ComboCel.addItem("")
self.ComboTrenirovki = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
self.ComboTrenirovki.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(780, 170, 171, 22))
self.ComboTrenirovki.setObjectName("ComboTrenirovki")
self.ComboTrenirovki.addItem("")
self.ComboTrenirovki.addItem("")
self.ComboTrenirovki.addItem("")
self.ComboTrenirovki.addItem("")
self.ComboTrenirovki.addItem("")
self.ComboTrenirovki.addItem("")
self.ComboTrenirovki.addItem("")
self.ComboTrenirovki.addItem("")
self.LineVivodCalc = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
self.LineVivodCalc.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(780, 420, 171, 91))
self.LineVivodCalc.setObjectName("LineVivodCalc")
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: @S.Nick, готово

Comment: А stacktrace при краше есть возможность получить?

Comment: `self.LineVivodCalc.setText(muzh_rashod)`
В этой строке проблема

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пожалуйста, предоставляйте минимально-воспроизводимый пример, а не отрывки кода.

Попробуйте:

```
import re
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        
        self.comboFizAkt = QtWidgets.QComboBox() 
        self.comboFizAkt.addItems(
            ["Сидячий", 
             "Слабый физ. труд", 
             "Преобладает физ. труд",
             "Очень тяжёлый физ. труд"
            ]
        )
        self.comboCel = QtWidgets.QComboBox() 
        self.comboCel.addItems(
            ["Ничего не хочу", 
             "Хочу похудеть", 
             "Хочу улучшить фигуру",
             "Хочу набрать мыш. массу"
            ]
        )
        self.comboTrenirovki = QtWidgets.QComboBox() 
        self.comboTrenirovki.addItems(
            ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7+"]
        )        
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Проверить выбор пользователя")
#        self.button.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)
#        self.comboFizAkt.activated.connect(self.comboActivated)     # (self.label.clear)
#        self.comboCel.activated.connect(self.comboActivated)        # (self.label.clear)
#        self.comboTrenirovki.activated.connect(self.comboActivated) # (self.label.clear)
        
        self.polMuzh = QtWidgets.QCheckBox('М')
        self.polZhen = QtWidgets.QCheckBox('Ж')
        widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        layoutH = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(widget)
        layoutH.addWidget(self.polMuzh)
        layoutH.addWidget(self.polZhen)
        self.cb = ''
        self.polMuzh.stateChanged.connect(self.calc_logic1)    
        self.polZhen.stateChanged.connect(self.calc_logic2)
#+++
        self.lineVozrast = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()  
        self.lineVes = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.lineRost = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()        
        
        layout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self)
        layout.addRow(QtWidgets.QLabel("Уровень физической активности:"), self.comboFizAkt)
        layout.addRow(QtWidgets.QLabel("Ваша цель:"), self.comboCel)
        layout.addRow(QtWidgets.QLabel("Кол-во тренировок в неделю:"), self.comboTrenirovki)
        layout.addRow("Ваш пол:", widget) 
#+++
        layout.addRow("Ваш возраст:", self.lineVozrast)
        layout.addRow("Ваш вес:", self.lineVes)
        layout.addRow("Ваш рост:", self.lineRost)
        
        layout.addRow(self.button) 
        layout.addRow(self.label)

    # логика калькулятора расхода калорий для мужчин
    def calc_logic1(self, toggle):
        if toggle == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            self.polZhen.setEnabled(False)

            if self.comboFizAkt.currentText() == 'Сидячий' and \
               self.comboCel.currentText() == 'Ничего не хочу' and \
               self.comboTrenirovki.currentText() == '0':
                string_vozrast = self.lineVozrast.text()
                string_vozrast1 = int("0" + "".join(list(map(str, re.findall(r'\d+', string_vozrast)))))
                if 10 <= string_vozrast1 < 112:
                    string_ves = self.lineVes.text()
                    string_ves1 = int("0" + "".join(list(map(str, re.findall(r'\d+', string_ves)))))
                    if 635 > string_ves1 >= 30:
                        string_rost = self.lineRost.text()
                        string_rost1 = int("0" + "".join(list(map(str, re.findall(r'\d+', string_rost)))))
                        if 272 > string_rost1 >= 55:
                            muzh_rashod = 5 + (10 * string_ves1) + (6.25 * string_rost1) - (5 * string_vozrast1)
# !!!                           self.label.setText(muzh_rashod)
                            self.label.setText(str(muzh_rashod))        # <<<=======
        else:
            self.polZhen.setEnabled(True)
#            self.label.setText('Вы ввели неверные данные!')
            self.label.clear()

    # логика калькулятора расхода калорий для женщин
    def calc_logic2(self, toggle):

        if toggle == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            self.polMuzh.setEnabled(False)

            if self.comboFizAkt.currentText() == 'Сидячий':
                if self.comboCel.currentText() == 'Ничего не хочу':
                    if self.comboTrenirovki.currentText() == '0':
                        string_vozrast = self.lineVozrast.text()
                        string_vozrast1 = int("0" + "".join(list(map(str, re.findall(r'\d+', string_vozrast)))))
                        if 10 <= string_vozrast1 < 112:
                            string_ves = self.lineVes.text()
                            string_ves1 = int("0" + "".join(list(map(str, re.findall(r'\d+', string_ves)))))
                            if 635 > string_ves1 >= 30:
                                string_rost = self.lineRost.text()
                                string_rost1 = int("0" + "".join(list(map(str, re.findall(r'\d+', string_rost)))))
                                if 272 > string_rost1 >= 55:
                                    zhen_rashod = (10 * string_ves1) + (6.25 * string_rost1) - (5 * string_vozrast1) - 161

                                    self.label.setText(str(zhen_rashod))        # <<<=======
        # <---- сдвинуть на 4 позиции
        else:
            self.polMuzh.setEnabled(True)
#                self.label.setText('Вы ввели неверные данные!')
            self.label.clear()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Всё работает, спасибо! Насчёт кода - учту.

Comment: @vis-a-vis вы не правильно даете имена переменным, почитайте пожалуйста https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/pep-8-rukovodstvo-po-napisaniyu-koda-na-python.html